# How to reduce request body in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Sometimes I'm facing too big Elasticsearch queries with duplicated parts with applying the same filtering structure into aggregations (for every aggregation field). Such queries are too massive for inspecting them. Is there any way to decrease request body size? A kind of aliases maybe, I need something like variables in YAML. Or maybe you could suggest something else. Thanks!

Comment: A first step would be to show your query. Easier to visualize for people who want to help.

Comment: I agree, but the first respondent got the point already so the issue resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look on search templates. You'll be able to store query templates in the cluster, use variables and even build dynamic queries:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html

Using this feature will reduce your request body dramatically as you'll just refer a pre registered template, providing some parameters if needed.

Repeating blocks and conditional sections are possible using mustache templating language http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just what I was looking for!